# F# Mutable Variables inside closures - IDictionary.Item

Tags: f#

I am trying to iterate through an IDictionary (reasons explained later...) in F#, and round each value to a specified precision. Essentially this is what I'm trying to do:

```
List.iter (fun(x) -> a.Item(x) <- Math.Round(a.Item(x), input.precision)) (ICollectionToDoubleList a.Keys)
```

(where ICollectionToDoubleList takes the ICollection a.Keys and casts it to a double list).
However since you can't alter mutable variables inside closures, this doesn't compile.

My first attempt at a solution was this:

```
List.iter (fun(x) ->    let p = Math.Round(a.Item(x), input.precision)
                        a.Item(x) := p
                        ) (ICollectionToDoubleList a.Keys)
```

However I'm getting the error:

```
This expression was expected to have type
    'a ref
but here has type
    double
```

on *a.Item(x)*

I could convert the IDictionary into two lists (or a list of tuples), perform the rounding, and re-cast into an IDictionary, but this seems a bit messy and convoluted.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention a was defined as:

```
let mutable (a : IDictionary<double,double>) = ...
```

Comment: Just a quick question, why not the immutable `Map`? The code would be much simpler then :)

Comment: I don't want to create a new collection if at all possible.

Comment: Ummm... OK, and why is that? I'm just curious...

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
a.Item(x) <- p
```

In F# you use `<-` to assign to mutable values, whilst `:=` assign to `ref` values.

You could even use

```
a.[x] <- p
```

for a slightly simpler version.

Explaination of what mutable means (it behaves like the opposite of const in C)

```
let mutable m = [|1|]
let t = [|1|]
m.[0] <- 0
t.[0] <- 0 //neither of these change m or t - only elements so they are fine
m <- [|1;2;3;|]  //fine as m is mutable
t <- [|1;2;3;|]  //not allowed as t is not mutable
```

If you are used to `const` in C, the above are roughly equivalent to

```
int* m = {1};
const int* t = {1}
```

note, neither is equivalent to

```
const int* q const = {1}
```

which is I think what you thought not mutable meant.

Comment: This would work outside of an enclosure, but I'm using this within an enclosure.

Comment: Really, this compiles for me - `> let test = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,int>()
List.iter (fun(x) -> test.Item(x) <- 5) ([]);;`

Comment: That's a quirk of FSI I believe! It does not compile in VS 2012 when written as a source file.

Comment: @Nick - that code also compiles for me with the compiler.  Maybe post your complete example that doesn't compile.

Comment: You've not written test as mutable. It does compile without being mutable, however am I right in thinking that the List.iter would not actually do anything?

Comment: @Nick - the `iter` only doesn't do anything because the input list is `[]`.  You can still assign to elements of a non-mutable array / dictionary.  See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've discovered the answer...

I have defined a as:

```
let mutable (a : IDictionary<double,double>) = ...
```

If I change this to

```
let (a : IDictionary<double,double>) = ...
```

then this compiles. It seems a little counter-intuative to me that a non-mutable value can be mutated, but a mutatable variable cannot!!

Comment: Whether or not the reference to the dictionary is mutable has nothing to do with whether or not the dictionary allows things inside of it to be changed.